# Edge webdriver cannot find element visible to Firefox driver on SharePoint site

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to access a dialog box on SharePoint using the Edge driver, however, my code doesn't find it. Using the Firefox driver, it works without problems:

[image]

[The reason I have to use Edge is because I am in a corporate environment, and Firefox is not supported by our single sign-on, proxies etc.]

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Edge()
#driver = webdriver.Firefox()
base_url = r"..../project/carb2_0/filedirectory/_layouts/15/groups.aspx"

driver.get(base_url)
time.sleep(1)
           
group = "AT01"
button= driver.find_element_by_xpath(r"//a[contains(text(),'File Directory - "+group+"')]")
button.click()
time.sleep(0.2)        

button = driver.find_element_by_link_text("New")
button.click()
time.sleep(0.2)        
driver.switch_to.frame(1)
time.sleep(0.2)        
#t = driver.page_source
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    r"//div[@id='ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_peoplePicker_TopSpan']/input[2]"
)
```

The last line throws an exception when using Edge,

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_peoplePicker_TopSpan']/input[2]"}
  (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=85.0.564.41)
```

Firefox is perfectly fine. Digging deeper, reading the page source with `driver.page_source` yields two completely different results. For Edge it is

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

For Firefox I get a full page, including an `iframe`, which can be found by `find_element_by_xpath`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for a work around to get your script running or an answer to why the browsers render differently? - if you just want it to work, can you post the dom view from devtools I'm Edge and tell us which edge version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the above issue was 2-fold:

- switch to the correct frame
- find the exact xpath denoting the `<input>` field in the page

For the first part I used the following code:

```
for i, frame in enumerate(frames):
    if re.search('ms-dlgFrame', frame.get_attribute('outerHTML')):
        frame_id = i
        break
driver.switch_to.frame(frame_id)
```

It turns out the the correct frame_id was 2, not 1. It is not clear to me why the firefox (gecko) driver would work anyways (and the selenium IDE would select 1).

The second part boiled down to searching through the source of the HTML page and find the exact input element. Interestingly enough, the selenium IDE had only located a `<div>` around that element, and the firefox webdriver was forgiving enough to type into the correct field. The edge driver would not do that and claim that element was not writable. Once I had found the correct `<input>` field, everything worked fine.